# How write this overfull and underfull table correctly?

Tags: tables

I have a table which has too long word *Furosemide arr.* causing the `overfull` warning, and something causing the `underfull` warning

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{| p{.15\linewidth} | p{.06\linewidth} | p{.06\linewidth} | p{.06\linewidth} | p{.06\linewidth} | p{.06\linewidth} | p{.06\linewidth} | p{.06\linewidth} | p{.06\linewidth} | p{.06\linewidth} | }   
\hline
\textit{Sinus}           & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & 0 & 0 & 306 
        & 0 & 18 \\ \hline
\textit{Furosemide arr.} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & 0 & 0 & 20 
        & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tables.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(./test.tables.aux)
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 11--11
[]\OT1/cmr/m/it/10 Furosemide

Overfull \hbox (13.04031pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--15
[][] 
[1{/home/masi/.texlive2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.tables.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2016/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2016/texm
f-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on test.tables.pdf (1 page, 21354 bytes).
Transcript written on test.tables.log.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's wrong with a plain table?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{|l|*{9}{r|}}
\hline
\textit{Sinus}           & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 306 & 0 & 18 \\ \hline
\textit{Furosemide arr.} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to ensure the numeric cells all have the same width, use `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{|l|*{9}{S[table-format=3.0]|}}
\hline
\textit{Sinus}           & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 306 & 0 & 18 \\ \hline
\textit{Furosemide arr.} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0  & 0 & 0 & 20 & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Masi As usual, I cannot read your mind.

Answer (score 5):

You have specified the table to be too wide, (see first table) but there is no reason to use p columns here, you want decimal aligned numbers as in the second.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}

\begin{document}
\newlength\mylen
\begin{table}
\centering

\mylen=\dimexpr\linewidth-20\tabcolsep-11\arrayrulewidth\relax
\begin{tabular}{@{}| p{.37\mylen}| *{9}{ p{.07\mylen} |}@{}}
\hline
\textit{Sinus}           & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & 0 & 0 & 306 
        & 0 & 18 \\ \hline
\textit{Furosemide arr.} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & 0 & 0 & 20 
        & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\tabcolsep=5pt
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l| *{9}{D..{3.0}|}@{}}
\hline
\textit{Sinus}           & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & 0 & 0 & 306 
        & 0 & 18 \\ \hline
\textit{Furosemide arr.} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 
        & 0 & 0 & 20 
        & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the benefit of `@{}`? I have never used them in tables. - - What is `D` in `{D..{3.0}|}`? Decimal iterate with some length?

Comment: @Masi - Please read the user guide of the [dcolumn package](http://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn), which is loaded in the preamble of David's code, and familiarize yourself with the properties of the `D` column type.

Comment: @Masi any latex tutorial (and I'm sure some answers here) will describe `@` it is needed in the full width case to remove the outer column padding, in the second one it's just there because of cut and paste, but is a good idea anyway in case the text was a little wider, it would allow more space.

Answer (score 4):

I'd measure the widest elements in columns 2-10 and then set those columns to be that width (promoting some form of horizontal consistency). Also, using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to set the remaining (first) column to fill the full `\textwidth`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newlength{\templength}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \settowidth{\templength}{306}% Widest element in columns 2-10
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | X | *{9}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{\templength} |} } 
    \hline
    \textit{Sinus} & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0 
                   & 0 & 0 & 306 
                   & 0 & 18 \\
    \hline
    \textit{Furosemide arr.} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 
                   & 0 & 0 & 20 
                   & 0 & 5 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'd also use [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for a more appealing visual look. You'll gain a number of `\tabcolsep`s for each of the vertical rules that is not really needed.

Comment: What is 306 in your `\settowidth` command? - - Hmm - - it seems this only works with digits for the columns 2-10.

Comment: @Masi: `306` is the widest element in the 9 columns (column 2-10). Is store the length of `306` using `\settowidth{\templength}{306}` and use this width in `{9}{>{..}p{\templength}}`.

Comment: What do `3` and `6` stand for in `306`?

Comment: @Masi: It was part of your example. As I mention in the first paragraph, I use `306` - *which you supplied* - because it's the widest element in columns 2-10.

Comment: @Masi From the context I assume 306 is a decimal number, that means that 3 stands for the number of hundreds and 6 for the number of ones.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tabularx` the equal width of cells is simple to determine:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | l | *{9}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X |} }
    \hline
    \textit{Sinus} & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0
                   & 0 & 0 & 306
                   & 0 & 18 \\
    \hline
    \textit{Furosemide arr.} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0
                   & 0 & 0 & 20
                   & 0 & 5 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```