# How to prevent this overfull siunitx table of 4-digit numbers?

Tags: tables, siunitx

I want to have a siunitx table with four digits numbers like 1234 so I use `S[table-format=3.0]` but it gives the overfull hbox of the following code

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{9}{S[table-format=3.0]|}} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340832/13173
\hline
$B_{ij}$ & $B_{11}$ & $B_{22}$ & $B_{33}$ & $B_{44}$
& $B_{21}$ & $B_{31}$ & $B_{32}$
& $B_{123}$ & $n$ \\ \hline
\textit{Arr./AHB}        & 47 & 94 & 0 & 2
                & 0 & 0 & 2066
                & 0 & 47 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
)
Overfull \hbox (5.00002pt too wide) detected at line 16

[1{/home/masi/.texlive2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.tables.aux) )
```

Heiko's proposal `\begin{tabular}{|l|*{9}{S[table-format=4.0]|}}` gives

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
)
Overfull \hbox (6.16374pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--19
[][] 
[1{/home/masi/.texlive2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./test.tables.aux) )
```

### Better data to illustrate the problem clearer

```
% egrep
% fix for avoiding the overfull
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-\dimexpr 6.16374pt/20}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{9}{S[table-format=4.0]|}} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340832/13173
\hline
{$B_{ij}$} & {$B_{11}$} & {$B_{22}$} & {$B_{33}$} & {$B_{44}$}
& {$B_{21}$} & {$B_{31}$} & {$B_{32}$}
& {$B_{123}$} & {$n$} \\ \hline % Heiko
\textit{Masit}           & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0
                & 0 & 0 & 306
                & 0 & 18 \\ \hline
\textit{Arr./AHB}        & 47 & 94 & 0 & 2
                & 0 & 0 & 2066
                & 0 & 47 \\ \hline
\textit{Tiramisuta arr.}    & 24 & 0 & 0 & 2
                & 0 & 0 & 546 & 0 & 24 \\ \hline
\textit{Coca-colaPepsi arr.} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0
                & 0 & 0 & 20
                & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Output

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx-abbreviations.cfg
)
Overfull \hbox (38.51854pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 12--29
[][]
```

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: `1234` is covered by `S[table-format=4]`.

Comment: `S[table-format=4]` is correct for `1234`, but since all numeric columns are using this, the whole table gets too large.

Comment: The contents of the first row in the `S` columns should be enclosed in brackets.

Comment: For instance, you should write  {$B_{ij}$}, not    $B_{ij}$.

Comment: @wchargin Fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `table-format=4.0`, since one column has four digit numbers.

Next, look in your log file for the amount of overfilling, which is 6.16374pt; since there are ten columns, distribute the excess in the 20 intercolumn spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}

% fix for avoiding the overfull
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-\dimexpr 6.16374pt/20}

\begin{tabular}{|l|*{9}{S[table-format=4.0]|}} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340832/13173
\hline
$B_{ij}$ & $B_{11}$ & $B_{22}$ & $B_{33}$ & $B_{44}$
& $B_{21}$ & $B_{31}$ & $B_{32}$
& $B_{123}$ & $n$ \\ \hline
\textit{Arr./AHB}        & 47 & 94 & 0 & 2
                & 0 & 0 & 2066
                & 0 & 47 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Do this only when the table is in its final form. For instance, when the contents is

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{9}{S[table-format=4.0]|}} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340832/13173
\hline
$B_{ij}$ & $B_{11}$ & $B_{22}$ & $B_{33}$ & $B_{44}$
& $B_{21}$ & $B_{31}$ & $B_{32}$
& $B_{123}$ & $n$ \\ \hline
\textit{Arr./AHB}        & 47 & 94 & 0 & 2
                & 0 & 0 & 2066
                & 0 & 47 \\ \hline
\textit{Masit}           & 18 & 0 & 0 & 0
                & 0 & 0 & 306
                & 0 & 18 \\ \hline
\textit{Arr./AHB}        & 47 & 94 & 0 & 2
                & 0 & 0 & 2066
                & 0 & 47 \\ \hline
\textit{Tiramisuta arr.}    & 24 & 0 & 0 & 2
                & 0 & 0 & 546 & 0 & 24 \\ \hline
\textit{Coca-colaPepsi arr.} & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0
                & 0 & 0 & 20
                & 0 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I get an overfull of 44.68217pt, so the fix should become

```
% fix for avoiding the overfull
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-\dimexpr 44.68217pt/20}
```

[image]

When to stop? If the amount of overfilling is more than 60pt, the intercolumn space would be reduced to 3pt (its default value is 6pt), which could still be acceptable. I wouldn't go lower than 2pt (which corresponds to an overfilling by 80pt).

In this case, you should consider using `\small` or `\footnotesize` before `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: Please, see the body. I had to include better data set to illustrate the problem clearer.

Comment: @Masi And so? If you get larger overfull, use the amount you get informed about. Note that the usual setting to `\tabcolsep` is 6pt, so a reduction of 3pt is still acceptable. If you get more than 60pt overfull, you should consider using `\small` or `\footnotesize` before the tabular.

Comment: Great! The proposal `\footnotesize` is great because I want to prevent to warning always now when debugging my code.

Answer (score 4):

`1234` is covered by `S[table-format=4]`. However to table gets too wide, because all columns share the same setting. Then, the column headers are no longer centered.

The following example uses individual settings. Also it uses package `booktabs` for nicer horizontal rules. Also it avoids vertical lines to make a better looking table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{
    l
    *{2}{S[table-format=2]}
    *{4}{S[table-format=1]}
    S[table-format=4]
    S[table-format=1]
    S[table-format=2]
  }
    \toprule
    $B_{ij}$ & $B_{11}$ & $B_{22}$ & $B_{33}$ & $B_{44}$
    & $B_{21}$ & $B_{31}$ & $B_{32}$
    & $B_{123}$ & $n$ \\
    \midrule
    \textit{Arr./AHB}
    & 47 & 94 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 2066 & 0 & 47 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]