# How to make multirow "footnote row" for dominating cell in LaTeX Table?

Tags: tables, multirow, xtable

I want to minimise the dominating effect of big cells in tables within a table by the following

- have two major rows for each row where a dominating row such that the dominating cell will take place in the new major row. I call this option "footnote row" because you make a new full-width one-cell row for the dominating content.

Data are about MCQ questions which have own ids. 
They are not related so strict table structure is not mandatory. 
There is a table structure of 7 columns where one cell is dominating (biggest), causing much white space in the table (see Fig. 2). 
See Fig. 1 for a single row presentation, and repeat it for N rows and you get output like Fig. 2 where much white space.

Fig. 1 Output of one row where 1st column is set dominating (but without row ids which are in data sample now), 
Fig. 2 Low-resolution example output where too much white all over the place

[image]
[image]

Two rows of data `data.tex` where dominating cells are at 2nd and 3rd column, respectively

```
1 & What is the difference between technical picture of acute donald duck between dragon in early adulthood comparing with elderly? & South Dragon & North Dragon & Manifold manifolds & Manifest colonisation & Upper limit    &5 \\ \hline
2 & South Dragon & What is the difference between technical picture of acute donald duck between dragon in early adulthood comparing with elderly? & North Dragon & Manifold manifolds & Manifest colonisation & Upper limit    &5 \\ \hline
```

Pseudocode

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex} % Bernard
\begin{document}

\begin{ltablex}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|p{.25\linewidth}|X|X|X|X|X|l|} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/340832/13173

1 & What is the difference between technical picture of acute donald duck between dragon in early adulthood comparing with elderly? & South Dragon & North Dragon & Manifold manifolds & Manifest colonisation & Upper limit    &5 \\ \hline
% TODO processhere the second dominating column cell into a new row taking full linewidth.  

\end{tabularx}
\end{ltablex}

\end{document}
```

TeXLive: 2016
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: You can't insert a `tabularx` inside a `longtable`. The latter is not the multipage version of the `table` environment: , but the multipage version of `table+tabular`, and it has its own syntax for the caption. You can load the `ltablex` package, which brings the functionalities of `longtable` to `tabularx`.

Comment: @Bernard I integrated your proposal to the body with a reference to you. I am testing more because I noticed that the biggest column of my data is fluctuating a lot so I need to find first the biggest column.

Comment: That's normal. Long table has to do some calculations. Oh, by the way, you should add the directive `\keepXColumns` to your preamble, if you want tabularx to have the prescribed width (otherwise it will be considered a maximum, depending on the real contents of the cells).

Comment: @Bernard Can you please give an example about the latter as an answer? - - I did not get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure in my understanding of your questions ... is the following table what you looking for?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex} % Bernard
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}
{\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|*{5}{X|}l|} %
    \hline
1   &   \multicolumn{6}{|p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}{
        What is the difference between technical picture of acute donald duck between dragon in early adulthood comparing with elderly?}                \\ \hline
2   &   South Dragon & North Dragon & Manifold manifolds 
        &   Manifest colonisation & Upper limit    &    5   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
see, if the following solution is what you looking for:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ltablex} % Bernard
\keepXColumns
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand\subtab[2]{
    \multicolumn{6}{@{}>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{\textwidth}@{}}{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\hsize}%
    {|p{\dimexpr0.05\hsize-2\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth\relax}|
      p{\dimexpr0.95\hsize-2\tabcolsep\relax}|}
      #1    &   #2    
     \end{tabular*}}
                      }

\begin{document}
{\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{X|}l|} %
    \hline
\subtab{1}{What is the difference between technical picture of acute donald duck between dragon in early adulthood comparing with elderly?
                                     }                      \\ \hline
South Dragon & North Dragon & Manifold manifolds
        &   Manifest colonisation & Upper limit    &    5   \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks very nice. There is one thing which I would like to change. No row-number for the second row. The first number is the MCQ ID. Is that possible?

Comment: this is not so simple :(. see addendum to my answer, if I understand your question.

Comment: Let's stick to the first version. - - Can you implement the output with only changes in preamble? - - Assume you have 777 rows of such data. One Question and its options at the same line. - - I am thinking how it is smart to make this for a general case. What do you think?

Comment: your last request is over my knowledge, i.e. it is impossible for me. maybe someone else know this, so i suggest you to ask this as new question, that will be more visible to audience.

Comment: I expanded N case situation here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346033/13173 I accepted your answer because it is excellent starting point to think about N case situation.